# PHP Graph library for iPhone and Android

Tags: php, android, jquery, iphone

I have been using Open Flash Chart 2 for my web applications.

Now I am building a website for mobile usage for iPhone and Android users.

Can you guys suggest the best alternative to OFC2 for iPhone and Android?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite has to be http://www.highcharts.com/. They boost cross platform/device compatibility and are also purely javascript. It took me a while to wrap my head around their documentation, but they provide a great solution over-all.

For non-commercial projects you can use Highcharts for free, otherwise you'd need to purchase a license for use.

**Update:** Here are a few other solutions that might help you.

http://code.google.com/p/flot/ - Uses jQuery & Draws using Canvas (it'll work in all modern browsers and devices) These charts are interactive and can be customized quite a lot.

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/ - This is another one I've checked out. It also uses jQuery & Canvas.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ - Google Charts might be worth trying out. They are quite easy to use, however they are simple and don't offer much in ways of customizing interactive charts. You can use the wizard to easily build charts: http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks, But I wanted a charting solution that's free for commercial and non-commercial usage.

Comment: In that case, it depends on the functionality you require. I've researched quite a few different browser based charting solutions and have noticed that they all have their pros and cons. I'll update my answer with a few other alternatives (i'm not sure on any of their licensing)